# Blazor Client Side authentication jwt or cookies

Tags: c#, blazor

So i am experimenting with client side blazor and trying to figure correct implementation for JWT or Cookie authentication.
Suppose that i have a service that serves the tokens and refresh token on client side i will have multiple API Services that will need to use this token or cookies to create API requests.

So as i understand i will need to implement and API Service classes similarly as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

So in order to have a consistent authentication state an Authentication service should be introduced and injected to the API Service classes. This service will have the responsibility of doing auth,getting initial token and doing a refresh token when required.

So with the latest release of Blazor there is this new component called AuthenticationStateProvider, the use of it seem to be clear but the question is would it be correct approach to use this as a global Authentication service?

Answer (score 1):

So HttpClientFactory is not supported on the client. In client-side Blazor, HttpClient is added to the DI system, and you can inject it into your components or classes.

So you want to use AuthenticationStateProvider as global Authentication service ? I'm not familiar with this component, but I'm afraid, from the short read I had after reading your question, that it is not an authentication system, but a tool to provide authentication state information, such as user age, etc. You still need to configure the Jwt middle ware, create a controller responsible for issuing the Jwt token, and so on. And I guess that you can employ the AuthenticationStateProvider to provide your client app with authentication state before a user, say, logged in and after, etc. I do hope I'm not wrong about it, at least not entirely.

So hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

When using JWTs on unsecure clients like SPAs, it's a bad practice to implement refresh tokens, as those are meant to be private.

The current OIDC recommendation (for SPAs) is to implement the Authentication Code Grant strategy.

I would recommend you to take a look at Blazor-Auth0 library (author here), it implements the Authentication Code Grant strategy blacked on Auth0, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel (and it's free).

Even if you don't want to add a new dependency, you would find it as a good source of examples of how to implement JWT authentication and authorization in Blazor.

https://github.com/henalbrod/Blazor.Auth0

Comment: Thanks for the sample, indeed it makes things clearer and the way its implemented with separation of AuthenticationStateProvider and AuthenticationService makes the code more clean and extendable. Now i dont want to use any external services for the auth and your comment that JWT is not suitable for SPA has intrigued me , i though that JWT would be the most common approach for such applications?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, JWT was born for the web, but, the refresh token's don't. Refresh token's are meant to be used in secure environments (aka server side) where secrets can be stored securely.

Comment: I think the wording was confusing, I just changed it to avoid confusion, thanks for your comments.

Comment: @HenryRodriguez Your position about refresh tokens isn't exactly true. The whole point of refresh tokens is to solve the problem of JWTs effectively being static. By using a short lived access token (JWT) and a long lived refresh token (GUID) you gain the ability to revoke access on a per-device level while keeping the claims reasonably up to date, while also getting the majority of the benefits from signed json web tokens.

At some point, you have to store some key on the client to be able to access the API. There's no purpose making it more complex just to store another key on the client.

Comment: That would maybe apply for devices, but I'm afraid is not the recommended way to go when we talk about SPAs

Comment: @HenryRodriguez Even for SPAs, storing a refresh token is fine. It's just how you store it that matters. You want to store the refresh token in a cookie so XSS attacks won't have access to it.

It's no different from storing a session key in terms of client-side security. And, no matter what, *something* always has to be stored client-side.

Comment: Again, you can think "it is fine" and maybe "it just works" but again, is not the recommended way to do it in SPAs anyway

Comment: @HenryRodriguez Are session key's more secure than cookies? I'm interested in what your saying but you haven't really addressed these points